# php/mysql comments duplicating automatically on pages reload

Tags: comments

I have created a commenting system for my website. The problem I have is that, the old comments duplicate themselves anytime the webpage is refreshed or reloaded.
How can I stop this and only show original comments?
I have added the entire code here below:

```
<pre>
require 'data/connect.php';


 if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['comment'])){
     $name = trim($_POST['name']);
     $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);

     if(!empty($name) && !empty($comment)){
         $insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO 
         comments(name,comment)VALUES('$name','$comment')");
         if($insert){
             echo "Success";
         }else{
             echo "Sorry";
         }
     }
 }
 ?>
 </pre>
```

form here

```
<pre>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['comment'])){
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($comment)){
             $query = $connect->query("SELECT name,comment FROM comments WHERE name='$name' AND comment='$comment'");
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                echo "<b>",$row->name,"</b><br/>",$row->comment;
            } 
        }
    }
   ?>
</pre>
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Send out a unique value (created with php's `uniqid()` for example) in a hidden field in the form.  Every time you send the form to a browser, change the value.   If you get the same value twice from the same browser, you know it was a double post.

You could also compute a hash of the posted information and compare that against hashes of what's already in the database, for speed, you could store the hash for each comment in the database.

You may also be able to restrict this at the database level, for example by using replace instead of insert (for mySQL).

Comment: Ok, i've updated my spelling and added some missing words.  I must have been falling asleep as I wrote this.  This is a valid answer, and I use the technique successfully for the same purpose (commenting system with double posts).  If you're going to down-vote, at least give a reason.